# Understanding the profiler: Is pattern matching/de-structuring expensive?

Tags: performance-tuning, debugging

I was profiling some code and I am trying to understand what the results mean. Suppose we have the very idiomatic,

```
f[t_, s_] := t - s
Table[f[i, j], {i, 1000}, {j, 1000}] // RuntimeTools`Profile
```

I get that,

[image]

What piques me is the nearly 6 seconds lost between the two arrows. Please correct me if I am reading the profiling results wrong, but I am interpreting it as the 1 million calls to `f[i,j]` took 10.7 seconds to execute and the 1 million calls to `f[t_,s_]` took 4.7 seconds to execute. Is that an accurate way to read it?  So where did those 6 seconds go?

Changing it to read:

```
f[{t_, s_}] := t - s
xx = Join @@ Table[{i, j}, {i, 1000}, {j, 1000}];
f /@ xx ; // RuntimeTools`Profile
```

results in:

[image]

which is a two-second improvement. So pre-allocating the array saved some time, but that still doesn't explain the ~3.7 seconds between the 1 call to `Map` and the 1m calls to `f[{t_,s_}]`. There is also a 3 seconds difference between the time to execute the 1m calls to `f[{t_,s_}]` and 1m executions of `t-s`. What is that single extra call to `f` at the bottom?

So what is going on? 1 million subtractions should definitely not be taking that long on a modern PC. So I tried

```
Table[i - j, {i, 1000}, {j, 1000}]; // RuntimeTools`Profile
```

and

```
xx = Join @@ Table[{i, j}, {i, 1000}, {j, 1000}];
Map[#[[1]] - #[[2]] &, xx]; // RuntimeTools`Profile
```

which one can verify run readily under a second.

So is pattern-matching of the arguments/definitions of `f` an expensive process or is this just profiler overhead?

**EDIT**

---

I do understand one case is giving a list of lists and the other is a single list (that is a bit oversight on my part) but I think the essential question remains unchanged vis-a-vis `f`.

Comment: I do not have answers (and these are good questions). One possible way to assess profiler overhead is to test these variations in absence of profiling. Do they give similar results or remain apart by similar percentages?